# How Should i update a table depending on Comma Seperated Values in a string variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @CheckListId varchar(30);
SET @CheckListId='4,5,6,7'
```

How Should i update the CheckStatus Column row as 1 remaining rows as 0 for CheckStatus Column depending on the input @CheckListId(which will be the id's of CheckListId in drive.TableName)

which will be best approach for this problem??
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jieN.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `@CheckList` as a table.  For instance:

```
DECLARE @CheckListIds TABLE (id varchar(30));

INSERT INTO @CheckListIds (id)
    VALUES (4), (5), (6), (7);
```

Then:

```
update t
    set checkstatus = (case when cli.id is not null then 1 else 0 end)
    from t left join
         @CheckListIds cli
         on t.id = cli.id;
```

More:  Don't store lists as delimited strings.  This is particularly bad for numeric values, which should be stored as numbers.

Comment: Providing your values in a table allows to write `UPDATE YourTable Set CheckStatus=1 WHERE CheckListId IN(SELECT id FROM @CheckListIds)` @HarishKumar, You've deleted your comment now... Don't know if this is still useful...